# Como adicionar novas propriedades em um usuário utilizando Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Como posso criar novas propriedades utilizando o UserIdentity que vem por padrão quando se cria uma aplicação MVC 5?

Também, é interessante colocar informações que não pertencem diretamente a autenticação e autorização na classe UserIdentity?

Em meu sistema, além das informações de profile do usuário, ele terá um carrinho de compras, uma lista de endereço e movimentações. Estas informações devem estar em UserIdentity mesmo?

Estou utilizando EntityFramework CodeFirst com DataAnnotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Como posso criar novas propriedades utilizando o UserIdentity que vem por padrão quando se cria uma aplicação MVC 5?

Estendendo a classe `IdentityUser`. Por exemplo:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

## Também, é interessante colocar informações que não pertencem diretamente a autenticação e autorização na classe UserIdentity?

Sim. Tudo depende das necessidades do seu sistema. Não há qualquer problema em adicionar quaisquer propriedades que julgar necessárias para o bom funcionamento do seu sistema.

## Em meu sistema, além das informações de profile do usuário, ele terá um carrinho de compras, uma lista de endereço e movimentações. Estas informações devem estar em UserIdentity mesmo?

A melhor maneira de fazer isso é criando um outro *Model* que referencie o `IdentityUser` e nele fique as características de negócio. Isso se deve pelo fato que o `IdentityUser` não necessariamente funcionar sincronizado com o contexto principal da sua aplicação em Entity Framework, o que exigiria mais código customizado do que realmente precisa.

[Há um artigo no CodeProject em que isso é largamente discutido](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/682113/Extending-Identity-Accounts-and-Implementing-Rol), inclusive com algum código no GitHub.

Comment: Cigano, como assim o IdentityUser não necessariamente funciona sincronizado com o EntityFramework?

Comment: Acho que me expressei mal. No fundo ele usa, mas em um contexto separado ao contexto geral da sua aplicação. Para fazer os dois contextos funcionarem sincronizado, isto exige algum código extra, mas pode ser feito.

Comment: Entendi... quando eu utilizo o código que você me forneceu, ele levanta a exception "Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType[...]", sabe dizer se isto é comum?

Comment: Este erro normalmente se refere a erros de digitação nos nomes das variáveis, e não têm a ver com o código que reproduzi pra você.